# How to fetch data from an excel sheet and get the output in set format?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm making a movie recommendation system. I need a python code which converts the data imported from an excel sheet to a set format (as shown below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuAH8.gif)

Code to import data from the excel sheet:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('project.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
df.head(40)
```

Output I get:

```
        USER       MOVIE    RATINGS
0   Julia Roberts   Shrek   2.5
1   NaN         V for Vendetta  3.5
2   NaN         Pretty Woman    3.0
3   NaN            Star Wars    3.5
4   NaN    While You Were Sleeping  2.5
5   NaN     Phone Booth 3.0
6   Drew Barrymore  Shrek   3.0
7   NaN       V for Vendetta    3.5
8   NaN     Pretty Woman    1.5
9   NaN        Star Wars    5.0
10  NaN      Phone Booth    3.0
11  NaN   While You Were Sleeping   3.5
12  Kate Winslet       Shrek    2.5
13  NaN       V for Vendetta    3.0
14  NaN        Star Wars    3.5
15  NaN       Phone Booth   4.0
16  Tom Hanks   While You Were Sleeping 2.5
17  NaN           V for Vendetta    3.5
18  NaN         Pretty Woman    3.0
19  NaN         Star Wars   4.0
20  NaN     Phone Booth 4.5
....
......
......
......
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mds3V.gif)

From here I need to have an output like this:

```
dataset={
 'Julia Roberts': {
 'Shrek': 2.5,
 'I am Legend':3.0,
 'V for Vendetta': 3.5,
 'Pretty Woman': 0,
 "My Sister's Keeper":5.0,
 'Star Wars': 3.5,
 'Me Before You': 3.0,
 'While You Were Sleeping': 2.5,
 'Phone Booth': 3.0},

 'Drew Barrymore': {'Shrek': 3.0,
 'V for Vendetta': 3.5,
 'Pretty Woman': 1.5,
 "My Sister's Keeper":4.0,
 'Star Wars': 5.0,
 'Phone Booth': 3.0,
 'While You Were Sleeping': 3.5},


 'Tom Hanks': {'V for Vendetta': 3.5,
 'Pretty Woman': 3.0,
 'Phone Booth': 4.5,
 'Star Wars': 4.0,
 'While You Were Sleeping': 2.5,
 'I am Legend':3.5},

 'Sandra Bullock': {'Shrek': 3.0,
 'V for Vendetta': 4.0,
 'Pretty Woman': 2.0,
 'Star Wars': 3.0,
 'I am Legend':4.5,
 "My Sister's Keeper":3.5, 
 'Phone Booth': 3.0,
 'While You Were Sleeping': 2.0}
}
```

Code I am using (but showing error):

```
max_nb_row = 0
for sheet in df.sheets():
  max_nb_row = max(max_nb_row, sheet.nrows)

for row in range(max_nb_row) :
  for sheet in df.sheets() :
    if row < sheet.nrows :
      print (sheet.row(row))
```

Comment: Can we have the dataframe as text instead of as an image, please? I can't test my code on an image.

Comment: I have included the dataset above.

Comment: Sorry, where? There's the expected output as text, but the input only exists as an image.

Comment: import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('project.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
df.head(40)

Comment: To show the output I have included the image.

Comment: Okay, but I don't have your excel file -.- This is getting silly. I need some input to work with. I'm not going to type the data into my dataframe manually.

Comment: But I need my data set in this format: dataset={
 'Julia Roberts': {
 'Shrek': 2.5,
 'I am Legend':3.0,
 'V for Vendetta': 3.5,
 'Pretty Woman': 0,
 "My Sister's Keeper":5.0,
 'Star Wars': 3.5,
 'Me Before You': 3.0,
 'While You Were Sleeping': 2.5,
 'Phone Booth': 3.0},

 'Drew Barrymore': {'Shrek': 3.0,
 'V for Vendetta': 3.5, ....................

Comment: I have included the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this incomprehensible one-liner:

```
df.ffill().groupby('user').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['movie'], x['ratings']))).to_dict()
```

---

To visualize what's happening, we'll use this smaller dataframe:

```
>>> df
             user           movie  ratings
0   Julia Roberts           Shrek      2.5
1             NaN  V for Vendetta      3.5
2             NaN    Pretty Woman      3.0
3  Drew Barrymore           Shrek      3.0
4             NaN  V for Vendetta      3.5
```

Step by step, this is what happens:

1. Use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to replace the `NaN` values in the `user` column with the name above.

   ```
                user           movie  ratings
   0   Julia Roberts           Shrek      2.5
   1   Julia Roberts  V for Vendetta      3.5
   2   Julia Roberts    Pretty Woman      3.0
   3  Drew Barrymore           Shrek      3.0
   4  Drew Barrymore  V for Vendetta      3.5
   ```
2. Use `groupby('user')` to group the data by user
3. Use `apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['movie'], x['ratings']))` to create dicts of `{movie: rating}` pairs.

   ```
   user
   Drew Barrymore    {'Shrek': 3.0, 'V for Vendetta': 3.5}
   Julia Roberts     {'Shrek': 2.5, 'V for Vendetta': 3.5, 'Pretty ...
   dtype: object
   ```
4. Call `to_dict()` on the final dataframe to get the desired result.

   ```
   {'Drew Barrymore': {'Shrek': 3.0, 'V for Vendetta': 3.5},
    'Julia Roberts': {'Pretty Woman': 3.0, 'Shrek': 2.5, 'V for Vendetta': 3.5}}
   ```

Comment: @SanchariGhosh So your column names are capitalized. Surely you're proficient enough in pandas to find a fix for that.

Comment: Yea I used the capital symbols of course but still showing error.

Comment: df.ffill().groupby('USER').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['MOVIE'], x['RATINGS']))).to_dict()

Comment: @SanchariGhosh Whatever the error you're getting is, I can't reproduce it. My code works with the dataframe you posted in your question. If it doesn't, I don't have enough information to help you figure out why. I don't know what the difference between your dataframe and the dataframe in the question is. Things like this are why it's important to include the dataframe in the question - if I can't reproduce your exact input, I can't help you figure out a solution.

Comment: But I did provide you the data and it is same as the one I am actually using.

Comment: @SanchariGhosh Well, yes, but clearly there must be a difference between the dataframe you used and the dataframe I used. I assure you that I've tested my code and that it works with the dataframe from the question.

Comment: I added one screenshot, if you can have a look.

Comment: @SanchariGhosh Look, I don't know what to tell you. [It works.](https://repl.it/@PaulPinterits/DarkturquoiseTransparentFacts)